# Passing Parameters in Python/Pytorch Classmethod

Tags: python, pytorch

I am confused while passing the parameters in classmethod.

The code is shown below:

```
def gather_feature(fmap, index):
    # fmap.shape(B, k1, 1)  index.shape(B, k2)
    dim = fmap.size(-1)
    index = index.unsqueeze(len(index.shape)).expand(*index.shape, dim)  # this works

    fmap = fmap.gather(dim=1, index=index)  # out[i][j][k] = input[i][index[i][j][k]][k]  # if dim == 1.
    return fmap
```

```
def gather_feature(fmap, index):
    # fmap.shape(B, k1, 1)  index.shape(B, k2)
    dim = fmap.size(-1)
    index = index.unsqueeze(len(index.shape))
    index = index.expand(*index.shape, dim)  # raise error
    
    fmap = fmap.gather(dim=1, index=index)  # out[i][j][k] = input[i][index[i][j][k]][k]  # if dim == 1.
    return fmap
```

Once *index.unsqueeze()* has done, the shape of *index* would be changed to (B, k2, 1).

If the *index.shape* that pass to *expand()* classmethod is (B, k2, 1), an error has raised.

However, if writing these tow classmethod in one line, namely *index.unsqueeze().expand()*, the *index.shape* passing to *expand()* classmethod seems to be (B, k2).

Has the *index.shape* **been computed and stored before performing** *.unsqueeze()*?

Therefore, the *.unsqueeze()* won't affect the *index.shape* which pass to *.expand()*.

That is my guess, but I cannot figure out another one.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the first case -

```
index.unsqueeze(len(index.shape)).expand(*index.shape, dim)
```

This is equivalent to the following code -

```
A = index.unsqueeze(len(index.shape))
index = A.expand(*index.shape, dim)
```

Note that Tensor `index` has not been changed after the execution of the first line. So when you then execute `A.expand(*index.shape, dim)` the original shape of `index` is used.

However in the second case you when you first do `index = index.unsqueeze(len(index.shape))` , you are changing `index`. So in the next step the new unsqueezed `index's` shape is used.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider that unsqueeze is not an in-place operation.